# What is the writing instret when IR bit is cleared in mcounteren register?

Tags: privileges, riscv, instruction-set

In RISC-V architecture, there is an instret CS Register which counts the retired instructions. There is an enable bit for this register in another register called mcounteren. The IR bit of this register is controlling the read operation from lower privilege levels. However, I cannot find any specific information about writing to instret when the relevant bit is zero. Does it also give illegal instruction like read operation or not?

Comment: Spec says: _The cycle, instret, and hpmcountern CSRs are read-only shadows of mcycle, minstret, and mhpmcountern, respectively._ So even with the IR bit set, writes are not allowed to instret as it's readonly CSR.

Comment: Thank you.
Yes, Writes are not allowed, but Should I also raise an illegal instruction exception?

Comment: Yes. Chapter 11 of riscv-spec Zicsr mentions the behavior of different CSR instructions. I try to think of it this way. (I maybe wrong). Given CSR number is part of the instruction itself, and func3 part of the instruction defines the type of operation (read/write/clear/set). We are actually creating an invalid instruction by using a write func3 and a read-only CSR number. Which will lead to Illegal instruction exception. func3 and csr numbers are from CSR instruction encoding in the spec under 11.1.